# How can I calculate this integral $ \int\frac{\ln^2(a+bx)dx}{x^n} $ through partial method $\int udv=uv-\int vdu$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I solve integral considerable number, but the following integral I could not solve.  It is about this integral:

$$
\int\frac{\ln^2(a+bx)dx}{x^n}
$$

I want to make the solution through partial method: $\int udv=uv-\int vdu$

I've solved the integral $$\int\frac{\ln(a+bx)dx}{x^n}$$.

Please help, thank you for your help preliminarily

Comment: What is the solution of the second integral? (I know I am being lazy:) )

Comment: Mathematica gives the solution in terms of some hypergeometric functions. I suspect you are not going to be able to do this by hand.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an (failed) attempt to find a reduction formula, and as @mtiano noted, the close form requires some hypergeometric functions. Let
$$\begin{align}
u =& \frac{\ln(a+bx)}{x^n} \\ 
du =& \frac{\frac{bx^n}{a+bx}-n x^{n-1}\ln(a+bx)}{x^{2n}}dx
 = \left[ \frac{b}{x^n(a+bx)}-\frac{n\ln(a+bx)}{x^{n+1}}\right]dx\\
dv =& \ln(a+bx) dx \\
v =& \frac{(a+bx)\ln(a+bx)}{b}-x
\end{align}$$

Also let (since OP has solved it)
$$I_n(x)=\int\frac{\ln(a+bx)dx}{x^n}$$

$$\begin{align}
J_n(x)=&\int\frac{\ln^2(a+bx)dx}{x^n}\\
=& \int\frac{\ln(a+bx)}{x^n}\ln(a+bx)dx\\
=& \frac{\ln(a+bx)}{x^n} \cdot \left[ \frac{(a+bx)\ln(a+bx)}{b}-x \right]- \\
 & \int{\left[ \frac{(a+bx)\ln(a+bx)}{b}-x\right] \left[\frac{b}{x^n(a+bx)}-\frac{n\ln(a+bx)}{x^{n+1}}\right]dx}\\
=& \frac{(a+bx)\ln^2(a+bx)}{bx^n}-\frac{\ln(a+bx)}{x^{n-1}} -\\
 & \int \left[ \frac{\ln(a+bx)}{x^n} - \frac{b}{x^{n-1}(a+bx)}- \frac{n(a+bx)\ln^2(a+bx)}{bx^{n+1}} +\frac{n\ln(a+bx)}{x^{n}}\right]dx \\
=& \frac{(a+bx)\ln^2(a+bx)}{bx^n}-\frac{\ln(a+bx)}{x^{n-1}} - (n+1) I_n(x) +\frac{na}{b} J_{n+1}(x) + nJ_n(x) +\\
 &  \int\frac{b\,dx}{x^{n-1}(a+bx)}\\
=& \frac{(a+bx)\ln^2(a+bx)}{bx^n}-\frac{\ln(a+bx)}{x^{n-1}} - (n+1) I_n(x) +\frac{na}{b} J_{n+1}(x) + nJ_n(x) +\\
 & \left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n-1} \int \frac{b\,dx}{a+bx}
 - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n-k}\int\frac{dx}{x^k} &\text{(1)}\\
=& \frac{(a+bx)\ln^2(a+bx)}{bx^n}-\frac{\ln(a+bx)}{x^{n-1}} - (n+1) I_n(x) +\frac{na}{b} J_{n+1}(x) + nJ_n(x) +\\
 & \left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n-1} \ln(a+bx) -\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n-1} \ln x - \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n-k}\frac{1}{(-k+1)x^{k-1}} &\text{(2)}\\
\end{align}$$
Notice, for line $\text{(1)}$, the final summation term exists only for $n \ge 2$. For line $\text{(2)}$, the second last term (involving $\ln x$) exists only for $n \ge 2$, and the final summation term exists only for $n \ge 3$.

Making $J_{n+1}(x)$ the main term,
$$\begin{align}
-\frac{na}{b} J_{n+1}(x)=& \frac{(a+bx)\ln^2(a+bx)}{bx^n}-\frac{\ln(a+bx)}{x^{n-1}} - (n+1) I_n(x) + (n-1)J_n(x) +\\
 & \left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n-1} \ln(a+bx) -\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n-1} \ln x - \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n-k}\frac{1}{(-k+1)x^{k-1}}\\
J_{n+1}(x)=& -\frac{(a+bx)\ln^2(a+bx)}{nax^n}+\frac{b\ln(a+bx)}{nax^{n-1}} + \frac{b(n+1)}{na} I_n(x) - \frac{b(n-1)}{na}J_n(x) +\\
 & \left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n} \frac{\ln(a+bx)}{n}  -\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n} \frac{\ln x}{n} - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n-k+1}\frac{1}{(-k+1)x^{k-1}}\\
\end{align}$$

This gives a reduction formula for $J_{n+1}(x)$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$. Same as above, the second last term (involving $\ln x$) exists only for $n \ge 2$, and the final summation term exists only for $n \ge 3$. Lastly, I could not solve the base case
$$J_1(x) = \int \frac{\ln^2 (a + bx)dx}{x}$$
yet, and reading from [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln%5E2%20%28a%2bbx%29%7D%7Bx%7D%20dx) the solution requires polylogarithm function.